# Sentence construction, and meaning

Tags: comparative-constructions

> I have never been so sure about anything in my life **before**.
>
> I have never been so sure about anything in my life.
>
> I have never been **as** sure **as I am about this than** anything in my life.

Are all the above sentences grammatically correct?
Do all of them convey the same meaning?

Comment: The third sentence, with *as ... than*, is not idiomatic. *Than* is used with the complement of "difference" comparatives: *I have never been **more/less** sure about anything **than** I am about this*. "Equality" comparatives like *as X* and *so X* take complements with *as*: *I have never been **as/so** sure about anything **as** I am about this.*

Answer (score 1):

Consider StoneyB's suggestion for the third sentence. And that said, rest of the two are *okay*.

However, the meaning may change for those two.

> I've never been so sure about anything in my life ***before***

talks about the *point* of time you are talking.  So, when you utter that sentence, it is in the context of what *is* happening to you right now, at this moment.

But, on the other hand...

> I have never been so sure about anything in my life.

is a *general* statement and is *true* even at this point of time. And, probably for the future.

Consider an example:

You *just made* a new friend. While exchanging each others' information, you *formally* say...

> I have never been so sure about anything in my life.

This means you are giving a general statement and has *nothing* to do with the present situation.

Now, imagine that you and your friend are on trekking. You feel so energetic *today*. There's a big hill and you *confidently* tell your friend that you can *climb* it **for sure**.

> I have never been so sure about anything in my life **before**.

This means that **this time**, you are sure that you can climb the hill without any problem! *'Till now,'* you weren't *so sure* like this.

So, to repeat, when you add *'before'*, it talks about things 'till now'. When you don't add it, it makes a general sentence.